# k3s failed to get Kubernetes server version: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/version?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused"

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, iptables, k3s

I have a weird problem that I cannot understand.
Running a k3s cluster with an external mysql database on ubuntu server 18.04 LTSall the pods that come pre-install are running.
I connected my k3s cluster to GitLab and wanted to install Prometheus and Runners on my cluster.
However, the pod installation fails with :

```
Error: looks like "https://gitlab-org.gitlab.io/cluster-integration/helm-stable-archive" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://gitlab-org.gitlab.io/cluster-integration/helm-stable-archive/index.yaml: dial tcp: lookup gitlab-org.gitlab.io on 10.43.0.10:53: read udp 10.42.0.57:53088->10.43.0.10:53: read: connection refused
```

The ufw is disabled
looking around I found that this might be an iptables issue so I tried adding some rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT 3 -s 10.42.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 3 -d 10.42.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

this did not help:

I also tried :

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.42.0.0/16 -d <host_ip> -j ACCEPT
```

Also tried flushing reinstalling k3s etc. nothing seems to work.